# Did someone just do a sitewide rep recalc?

Tags: support, rep-recalc

I just lost 93 points in one day, with no downvotes, and it matches my /reputation calculation.  So it seems like someone is deleting a lot of stuff, but they'd have to do a recalc for that to impact me.  So did someone go an do a sitewide rep recalc?

**EDIT:**  It's happened on other SE sites also.

**EDIT:**  Looks like they decided to punish the users with site-wide recalcs across all sites, as per [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-drop-in-reputation-find-out-reason-recalc).

Comment: No longer counting off topic questions that were deleted would do that

Comment: @random, as you know, there are plenty of on-topic questions that get deleted every day, I know on Meta I burn a lot of undelete votes trying to keep that from happening.

Comment: It's not a punishment.

Comment: @ChrisF, Yes it is, it's saying that a bunch of the work I did will not be rewarded.  There are many workarounds, but they decided to take the easy way out, and just dock everyone points.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see on Meta [Sudden sharp reputation drop problem: points disappeared and score lost (recalc?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-reputation-drop-problem-points-disappeared-and-score-lost-recalc) there was a site-wide re-calc,

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if they deleted it. I think they simply went to a backup. The reputation calculation just stops at Feb. 25th for me.

Comment: They didn't go to a backup, as @Lance mentions in his question - a site-wide rep recalc was triggered to accomodate for changes in `/users` page. Read more info [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-drop-in-reputation-find-out-reason-recalc)